# How can I correctly write a function? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, function

Here is my definition:

```
def fill(df_name):
   """
   Function to fill rows and dates.
   """
   # Fill Down
   for row in df_name[0]:
       if 'Unnamed' in row:
           df_name[0] = df_name[0].replace(row, np.nan)

   df_name[0] = df_name[0].ffill(limit=2)
   df_name[1] = df_name[1].ffill(limit=2)

   # Fill in Dates
   for col in df_name.columns:
       if col >= 3:
           old_dt = datetime(1998, 11, 15)
           add_dt = old_dt + relativedelta(months=col - 3)
           new_dt = add_dt.strftime('%#m/%d/%Y')

           df_name = df_name.rename(columns={col: new_dt})
```

and then I call:

```
fill(df_cars)
```

The first half of the formula works (columns 0 and 1 have filled in correctly). However, as you can see, the columns are labeled 0-288. When I delete this function and simply run the code (changing df_name to df_cars) it runs correctly and the column names are the dates specified in the second half of the function.

What could be causing this to not execute the `# Fill in Dates` portion when defined in a function? Does it have to do with local variables?

```
                                     0    1       2         3         4         5    ...  287  288  289  290  291 292
0                             France  NaN  Market      3330      7478      2273  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
1                             France  NaN   World       362       798       306  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
2                             France  NaN       %  0.108709  0.106713  0.134624  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
3                            Germany  NaN  Market      1452      2025      1314  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
4                            Germany  NaN  World       209       246       182  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
..                               ...  ...     ...       ...       ...       ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..
349                         Slovakia    0   World         1         1         0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
350                         Slovakia    0       %       0.5       0.5         0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaT
```

Comment: `df_name = df_name.rename(...)` This step won't do anything because df_name is a local variable. You need to return `df_name`, and change the call to `df_cars = fill(df_cars)`.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thanks a million!